# React Native Expo orientation listener without changing orientation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, screen-orientation

I'm tryin to detect the current orientaiton on my React Native app without having to change the orientation. I made a camera app and I want to flip the icons only when the orientation changes. Right now I can't use `ScreenOrientation.addOrientationChangeListener(listener)` without the actual orientation changing. Any ways around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the requirement is to get the device orientation even though the actual orientation has not been changed because it locked by [`orientation`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/#orientation).

You can use [`DeviceMotion`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/devicemotion/#devicemotionaddlistenerlistener) module to get the device rotation ([Euler angle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/device-orientation#rotation_data))

The exact calculation is taken from https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2430#issuecomment-538074235

```js
function orientationCalculation(gamma: number, beta: number) {
  let ABSOLUTE_GAMMA = Math.abs(gamma);
  let ABSOLUTE_BETA = Math.abs(beta);
  let isGammaNegative = Math.sign(gamma) == -1;
  let orientation = 0;

  if (ABSOLUTE_GAMMA <= 0.04 && ABSOLUTE_BETA <= 0.24) {
    //Portrait mode, on a flat surface.
    orientation = 0;
  } else if (
    (ABSOLUTE_GAMMA <= 1.0 || ABSOLUTE_GAMMA >= 2.3) &&
    ABSOLUTE_BETA >= 0.5
  ) {
    //General Portrait mode, accounting for forward and back tilt on the top of the phone.
    orientation = 0;
  } else {
    if (isGammaNegative) {
      //Landscape mode with the top of the phone to the left.
      orientation = -90;
    } else {
      //Landscape mode with the top of the phone to the right.
      orientation = 90;
    }
  }
  return orientation;
}

DeviceMotion.addListener(({ orientation, rotation }) => {
  setOrientation(
    orientationCalculation(rotation.gamma, rotation.beta) === 0
      ? 'protrait'
      : 'landscape'
  );
});
```

Expo demo: https://expo.dev/@moshfeu/detect-orientation-by-device-motion?serviceType=classic&distribution=expo-go

Source code: https://github.com/moshfeu/detect-orientation-by-device-motion/

---

**Older Answer**

```js
DeviceMotion.addListener(({rotation}) => {
  const alpha = Math.abs(rotation.alpha);
  this.setState({
    orientation: alpha > 3 || (alpha > 0 && alpha < 0.5) ? 'landscape' : 'protrait'
  });
});
```

Live demo: https://expo.io/@moshfeu/snack-dc115508-fab4-4be4-818a-5a03f89725bd

---

**Oldest Answer**

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the current orientation on the app is load without the user changing the orientation.

If so, you can get it from [`ScreenOrientation.getOrientationAsync()`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/#screenorientationorientationinfo) which will return a `Promise` with one of the [possible values](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/#enum-types-1)

```
ScreenOrientation.getOrientationAsync().then(data => this.setState({data}));
```

Live example: https://snack.expo.io/@moshfeu/ff4c76

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. I want to detect when the phone is put in landscape. But I don't want to actually CHANGE the orientation when this happens. getOrientationAsync() doesn't get triggered when the actual orientation doesn't change :(

Comment: `without having to change the orientation`, `without the actual orientation changing` so I thought that you want to detect while the orientation didn't change so I'm not sure what's the case. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, I’m trying to lock the screen, but still be able to detect changes. I tried your code, but it keeps saying portrait :(

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. I ended up using {orientation} instead of {rotation}. Also worked and was more consistent!

Comment: @rago182 can you share your code ?

Comment: The calculation is not working

Comment: Thanks @Simon30! It's hard to keep track on the changes  I updated the answer with a brilliant code I found on Github, please take a look.

Comment: this code does not work when putting the phone flat down on a surface coming from a landscape view mode. How can we keep the phone in its current orientation when flat on the table ?

Comment: The top example works, but I've noticed an issue on iOS (real device). The `DeviceMotion.addListener` will stop listening if Chrome Debugging is enabled, making it very hard to work with. Has anyone come across this?

Comment: THIS IS AMAZONG. Have my screen locked on landscape when taking photos but can change icon orientation when the phone is moved to portrate

Answer (score 4):

In order to get this working, I needed to:

- Add code to componentDidMount:

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  if (await DeviceMotion.isAvailableAsync()) {
    DeviceMotion.addListener(this.calculateRotation)
  }

  // ...
}
```

- Add code to componentWillUnmount:

```js
componentWillUnmount() {
  DeviceMotion.removeAllListeners()
}
```

- Add a method to calculate the rotation based on beta and gamma, based on [a helpful answer on github](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2430):

```js
calculateRotation = ({rotation: {beta, gamma}}) => {
  let absGamma = Math.abs(gamma)
  let absBeta = Math.abs(beta)
  let rotate = 0

  if (absGamma <= 0.04 && absBeta <= 0.24) {
    // Portrait mode, on a flat surface.
    rotate = 0
  } else if ((absGamma <= 1.0 || absGamma >= 2.3) && absBeta >= 0.5) {
    // General Portrait mode, accounting for forward and back tilt on the top of the phone.
    rotate = 0
  } else {
    if (gamma < 0) {
      // Landscape mode with the top of the phone to the left.
      rotate = -90
    } else {
      // Landscape mode with the top of the phone to the right.
      rotate = 90
    }
  }
  this.setState({rotate})
}
```

- When I need to get the current rotation, call `this.state.rotate`. This tells how much a photo taken needs to be rotated for a right-side-up image.

```js
matchPhotoRotation = (photo) => {
  const {rotate} = this.state

  if (rotate === 0) return photo

  return ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
    photo.uri,
    [{rotate}],
  )
}
```

Comment: This is causing an error: DeviceMotion.addListener(this.calculateRotation) if you close the component aka window it'll give error that cannot set state an unmounted component.  Since this.calculateRotation is not done running when you close.

Answer (score 0):

I found [another solution on GitHub](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2430#issuecomment-538074235), similar to [Mosh Feu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362517/react-native-expo-orientation-listener-without-changing-orientation/61621520#answer-60362889) using DeviceMotion, but using gamma and beta (x and y axis) instead of alpha (z axis) to figure out the rotation of the device. In my case I achevied a more satisfying result with this technique.

```
isPortrait(gamma: number, beta: number) {
 const ABSOLUTE_GAMMA = Math.abs(gamma);
 const ABSOLUTE_BETA = Math.abs(beta);
 const isGammaNegative = Math.sign(gamma) === -1;

 if (ABSOLUTE_GAMMA <= 0.04 && ABSOLUTE_BETA <= 0.24) {
  //Portrait mode, on a flat surface.
  return true;
 } else 
 if (
   (ABSOLUTE_GAMMA <= 1.0 || ABSOLUTE_GAMMA >= 2.3) &&
   ABSOLUTE_BETA >= 0.5
 ) {
   //General Portrait mode, accounting for forward and back tilt on the top of the phone.
   return true;
 } else {
   if (isGammaNegative) {
     //Landscape mode with the top of the phone to the left.
     return false;
   } else {
     //Landscape mode with the top of the phone to the right.
     return false;
   }
 }
}
```

And I call it in the listener from the componentDidMount method ([it's good practice to check sensor availability first with DeviceMotion.isAvailableAsync()](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/devicemotion/#devicemotionisavailableasync)):

```
const sensorAvailable = await DeviceMotion.isAvailableAsync();
if (sensorAvailable) {
 DeviceMotion.addListener(({ rotation }) => {
  const { gamma, beta } = rotation;
  this.setState({
    orientation: this.isPortrait(gamma, beta) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
   });
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution base on @Mosh Feu's answer, hope it help

```
DeviceMotion.addListener(({ rotation }) => {
  let ABSOLUTE_GAMMA = Math.abs(rotation.gamma);
  if (ABSOLUTE_GAMMA > Math.PI / 2) {
    const _gamma = ABSOLUTE_GAMMA - Math.PI;
    ABSOLUTE_GAMMA = Math.abs(_gamma);
  }
  const ABSOLUTE_BETA = Math.abs(rotation.beta);
  const gap = ABSOLUTE_BETA - ABSOLUTE_GAMMA;
  if (gap > 0.5) {
    console.log("portrait");
  } else if (gap < -0.5) {
    console.log("landscape");
  } else {
    console.log("unknow");
  }
});
```