# React Native Expo lock screen orientation but still detect orientation change

Tags: react-native, expo, screen-orientation

I'm trying to find a way to keep my screen orientation lock in React Native Expo, but still be able to detect a change in orientation. Why? I want to simply rotate a few icons when the person puts their phone in landscape instead of Expo changing the width into height and the height into the width.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a better way, but I'm using **unlockAsync** right after the screen locks into the desired orientation.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (isFullscreen) {
        await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE_LEFT);
      } else {
        await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT_UP);
      }
      ScreenOrientation.unlockAsync(); // <-- allow further rotation
    })();
  }, [isFullscreen]);
```

Comment: very interesting I have the same issue. I am going to give this a try and see if it works!

Comment: This is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362517/react-native-expo-orientation-listener-without-changing-orientation